# MongoDB ObjectId vs string in find()

Tags: mongodb

I'm starting to play with mongodb, and I learned that when inserting a document, you can either provide an ID, or let mongodb generate it for you.

I thought this is nice, because I want to let my users optionally choose an id, and if not generate it for them.

But the problem is, the generated one is of type `ObjectId` while the user provided one is a `string`, and the `find` method only returns the correct answer if you pass it with the **correct type**. So when a user requests `GET /widget/123`, I have no idea if the original ID was stored as an `ObjectId` or a `string` do I?

So how am I supposed to use this feature?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd recommend against letting users provide `_id`s: if 2 users want to use the same `_id`, the second user will be unable to, which will be frustrating. If users want that functionality, I'd recommend storing the user created id on a separate field & querying by user (or company or whatever) and the user-created id.

That said, mongo ObjectIds are 24 hex characters, so you can safely identify when an id is *not* a MongoId by checking whether it doesn't match `/^[a-f0-9]{24}$/` (or by seeing whether a call to `ObjectId("maybeAnObjectId")` throws). In the case where it's unclear (where a user might have provided 24 hex characters as their id), you'll need to use `$in` (or `$or`) to query for both cases:

`const query = /^[a-f0-9]{24}$/.test(id) ? { _id: {$in: [ObjectId(id), id]}} : {_id: id}`

(an annoying user could re-use an autogenerated ObjectId as their string id, and then queries to that route would return two values and there'd be no way of differentiating them).